# WebView is not loading webpage iOS 10 & Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am facing this strange issue. When I use url1, webView works fine. But when I use url2, webView sometimes doesn't load anything & only blank screen is displayed.

What should I do to solve this issue?

```
let url1 = "https://www.apple.com"

let url2 = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/music-video/despacito-feat-daddy-yankee/id1194807248"


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: url2)
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

}
```

Comment: try this: DispatchQueue.main.async { webView.loadRequest(urlRequest) }

Comment: for me opens my itunes app

Comment: I tried it on device & then it started working fine. In simulator iTunes url didn't load webView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on simulator, & trying to open an iTunes URL in WebView, then the webpage is not loaded in webview.

If you testing on device, then the webpage for iTunes URL gets loaded in webview.

Answer (score 0):

The below url

"https://itunes.apple.com/us/music-video/despacito-feat-daddy-yankee/id1194807248"

not handled by the `UIWebView` to load in simulator so try on device or open using `UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` mathod.